# Remove Outlook calendar requests without cancelling the meeting

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I have scheduled a whole raft of meetings in my Director's calendar and invited colleagues to attend. The director now does not need to attend the meetings - is it possible to delete them from his calendar without cancelling the meeting as the meeting will go ahead just with the other colleagues?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please tell us what version of Outlook you are using and what you have researched or attempted already.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook likes to send updates about any changes to meetings. For a meeting owner (originator) to delete a meeting from the calendar without sending a cancellation update, do the following;

**Note: DO NOT miss the first step, or you will send the cancellation.**

1. Set Outlook offline by clicking the Work Offline button on the
   Send/Receive tab (Outlook 2010/2013) or File, Work Offline in older
   versions (alternately, you can disable your network connection,
   either by unplugging the network cable or turning off the wireless
   adapter).
2. Cancel the meeting and choose Send Update button when finished.
3. Go to the Outbox, select the meeting update(s) and delete. Or you can
   open the meeting update then click X to close and the meeting
   disappears from the Outbox.
4. Repeat Step 1 to put Outlook back online.

[source](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/change-outlook-meetings-dont-send-updates/)